# How to defragment multiple EFI partitions?

Tags: windows-10, efi, defragment

I tried installing another non-windows (linux) operating system along side Win10 but due to some issues had to delete it later. Now after deleting the partitions that Linux was occupying, I see 2 Healthy EFI partitions size: 512MB and 190MB.

Can someone help me know if I could make them contiguous? If yes, how? Right-clicking on these partitions in Disk Management tool is not showing any options.

[image]

Comment: No; You won’t be able to combine those two partitions due to the system partition that exists between them.

Comment: @Ramhound Could it cause some problems in future if I leave them like this? What potentially could be stored in these?

Comment: Was the second "EFI System Partition" created during Linux installation? Does it have any files in it besides Linux GRUB?

Comment: @user1686 Yes, the second EFI System Partition was created to mount /boot/efi of the Linux installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the second EFI partition was created just for Linux, then you can safely delete it. You can browse it to make sure by assigning a disk letter using the `diskpart` tool. It's not exactly user friendly, but you'll have to deal with it anyway because *Disk Management* won't let you remove an EFI system partition. You'll also have to remove that letter before you can remove the partition.

Leaving the partition there isn't harmful, but makes your 34 GB of extra disk space unusable or usable only as a separate new partition. Deleting the 2nd ESP will let you expand your Windows system partition to assign the extra space to C:.